# Remove normalize css for particular div block

Tags: javascript, html, css, normalize-css

I have a normalize css for my existing website as below

```
p {
  font-family: Times new roman;
}
```

I have a new HTML component which cannot be changed as below

```
.abc {
  font-family:Helvetica;
}
<div class="abc">
  <p>abcdef</p>
</div>
```

When I integrate the new HTML component with my existing website the paragraph takes Times new roman. But my requirement is to show it as helvetica. I am in a critical challenge that I cannot change the existing website and the new component css.

I tried to write new css as below and it worked

```
.abc p {
   font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

But the problem is whenever the HTML component css changes I have to rewrite my css code. Is their any way to avoid existing normalize css only for the new HTML component block.

Comment: you can't "remove" a CSS rule, unfortunately. The only two options you have is "writing a more specific CSS rule that achieves what you need", or restructuring the CSS so that you don't just have a blind `.abc` class.

Comment: Anything paragraph inside `div.abc` should use Helvetica? Have you tried using `!imporatnt`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.abc, .abc * {
    font-family: Helvetica !important;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks. But if tomorrow the font is been changed to monospace I have to rewrite the css. Its been a huge change which is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
.abc p {
    font-family: inherit !important;
}
```

That will cause the paragraph inside .abc to inherit whatever font-family was declared for .abc, without declaring a specific font that may need to be changed.  You can also adapt this to any element that might be inside .abc.